# It is possible to maintain relation between two table in Hibernate level?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am new to Hibernate. Can you please answer my question?

Is it acceptable to maintain the 2 table relations in ORM level? I dont want to add foreign key relation between two tables, but I would like to add many to one relation in hbm file.

Ex I have Account and Account_Type tables. Account table contain AcntType column. Its not null column. AccountType contain AcntType as PK. There is no FK relation in Account table.

Now I would like to add relation from ORM level, I don't want to alter Account table and add foreign key constraint now.

I would like to add "many-to-one" attribute in my Account hbm file. I would like to add "one-to-many" attribute in my AccountType hbm file.

Is it acceptable to maintain relation in ORM level nor from DB level. I am using Oracle DB

Comment: Why don't you want to use a foreign key?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to maintain relation from Hibernate nor from DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't care if there is a foreign key constraint or not between the tables.

But adding a foreign key constraint guaranteees that, whatever you use to update your database, and whatever bug your code could have, you'll never have an account referencing an account type that does not exist. So you should definitely have a foreign key constraint.